# Codeginter $this->db->where() function concating "IS NULL" in query automatically when using find_in_set() function

Tags: codeigniter, find-in-set

I am writing a query in `codeigniter` with `FIND_IN_SET()` function.

```
   $this->db->where(FIND_IN_SET('".$value."',employer_job_location));
    $query_res= $this->db->get("employer_posted_jobs");
   echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
```

It is yielding

```
SELECT * 
FROM (`employer_posted_jobs`) 
WHERE (FIND_IN_SET('Delhi',employer_job_location)) IS NULL
```

In above query "IS NULL" is extra and it is very annoying.
Can anyone tell why this is coming with the query?
Thank you..

Comment: might [this](http://formyhelp.blogspot.in/2009/08/codeigniter-tweak-for-findinset.html) help?

Comment: Code was nice, but i am using column name from table and I can't add escape function to the column name

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must always check the results from the FIND_IN_SET() function somehow to make it work, try this:

```
$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$value',employer_job_location) !=", 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, However, it has worked with slightly different syntax:
$this->db->where(FIND_IN_SET('".$value."',employer_job_location) !=0);

Comment: You can always do `$this->db->where(sprintf("find_in_set('%d', employer_job_location) !=",$value), 0);`

Comment: can you please suggest any reference regarding this to understand it little deep. @MichaelK

Comment: @ankit suthar: You can find the documentation of MySQL find_in_set function here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set The rest is just basic syntax for Codeigniters Query Builder Class: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 0):

$this->db->where("FIND_IN_SET('$value',employer_job_location) !=", 0);